# Software TNC's for Linux? (targeted to BPSK1200)

Tags: digital-modes, modes, software

Are there any software TNC's (like [SoundModem](http://uz7.ho.ua/packetradio.htm)) for Linux?

This is limited to the ones which deal with BPSK1200 (used by cubesat projects).

For some cases [Warbler](http://members.casema.nl/b.ubbels/Warbler.htm) will suffice.

Comment: Your link to warbler is broken. If you mean WinWarbler, that doesn't really help a Linux user...

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean WinWarbler. Just updated the link.

Answer (score 1):

Soundmodem (the original from Thomas Sailor) is still (Debian Jessie) available for Linux. I used it recently with aprx to create a software TNC with a generic USB sound card for APRS purposes.

`apt-get install soundmodem`

Comment: I think the original soundmodem does not operate with BPSK1200.

Comment: Correct, however I noticed you have updated your question to ask specifically for this. Sorry, can't read your thoughts.. :-)

Answer (score 0):

[Paclink](http://paclink-unix.sourceforge.net/) is a Linux adaptation of [WinLink](http://www.winlink.org/) and might be a good place to start. As might the [TNC-Pi project](http://tnc-x.com/TNCPi.htm).